# Can I run heroku run rake db:migrate after using taps and heroku db:push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, database-migration, taps

I accidentally deleted my production database on heroku cedar stack several months ago.  I tried to recreate the db via `heroku run rake db:migrate`, but something was wrong with my migrations and it failed.  I then installed taps and did a `heroku db:push` and all was right with the world.

Can I now use `heroku run rake db:migrate` after running local migrations to update the production database, or am I forever tied to taps and `heroku db:push`?

Perhaps a better way to ask this question:  will `heroku run rake db:migrate` go through all of my migrations (and likely fail), or will it only go through migrations that have occurred since the last `heroku db:push`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `schema_migrations` table in your database. This is what Rails uses to determine which migrations to run. It has a single column containing each migration version Rails has applied to your application. For example, I have the following file in `db/migrate`:

- `20110415064108_create_users.rb`

`20110415064108` is listed as a row in my `schema_migrations` table. The same goes for every other migration file in `db/migrate` that existed since I last ran `rake db:migrate`.

Assuming taps *(which I know nothing about)* pushed this `schema_migraions` table in its entirety to production, you should be able to create new migrations and run them with `rake db:migrate` in production without trouble *(only those newly created migrations will be applied, since their version #s are the only ones missing from the production `schema_migrations` table)*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the schema_migrations table.  I just ran a migration, pushed it to production, and heroku run rake db:migrate worked.  Thanks.